# python interactive mode module import issue

Tags: python, namespaces, scope

I believe I have what would be called a scope issue, perhaps name space.  Not too sure I'm new to python.

I'm trying to make a module that will search through a list using regular expressions.  I'm sure there is a better way of doing it but this error that I'm getting is bugging me and I want to understand why.

here's my code:

```
class relist(list):
 def __init__(self, l):
  list.__init__(self, l)

 def __getitem__(self, rexp):
  r = re.compile(rexp)
  res = filter(r.match, self)
  return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re
    listl = [x+y for x in 'test string' for y in 'another string for testing']
    print(listl)
    test = relist(listl)
    print('----------------------------------')
    print(test['[s.]'])
```

When I run this code through the command line it works the way I expect it to; however when I run it through python interactive mode I get the error

```
>>> test['[s.]']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "relist.py", line 8, in __getitem__
    r = re.compile(rexp)
NameError: global name 're' is not defined
```

While in the interactive mode I do import re and I am able to use the re functions, but for some reason when I'm trying to execute the module it doesn't work.

Do I need to import re into the scope of the class? I wouldn't think so because doesn't python search through other scopes if it's not found in the current one?

I appreciate your help, and if there is a better way of doing this search I would be interested in knowing.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not run anything "ahead of time"; it runs code when it encounters it. The only thing that's done "ahead of time" is to translate the source code into bytecode.

When you import the module, `__name__` is the name of the module, rather than `__main__`. Thus, the code in the `if` block at the end is not executed, and `re` is not imported. When you then attempt to use the class, the name `re` is looked up right then, when it's needed (to access `re.compile`), and not found (because the module wasn't imported earlier).

Answer (score 2):

Move the "import re" out of the bottom "if..." to the top of the file:

```
import re

class ....
```

You're only importing the re module when run as a program, not imported as a module.

(Also, Python style prefers upper-case class names.)